# Best practice to find which variable is not null

Tags: c#

The only reason I'm asking this question is because it's very hard to articulate, in order to effectively Google search it.

Say I have 1000 different variables (1000 integers) and say we know that only 1 of them is not null.

How can I find that specific variable to get its value?

I thought about inserting all those variables into an array and traverse it until I find the correct one, but I wonder if there is more effective solution.

First of all, I thank you all for your answers. I'm totally sorry, but I failed to describe my issue precisely. I have an object with say 7 properties (I only wrote 1000 to emphasize the fact that there are more than 3 variables - obviously I exaggerated..). Anyway, I can check each and every one of those  properties, or I can do..what instead? Thanks again, and sorry I misdirected you all - my bad.

Comment: `null` means `0`? What is ineffective in an array?

Comment: How are the integers held? are they in an list, array or another object?

Comment: Is it nullable int? Because int's in c# can't be null

Comment: If you have 1000 different variables instead of a collection of 1000 elements you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Rotem Can you please show some code about the structure we are working against, and why it is you chose to define so many variables as opposed to storing this some other way. What is the end requirement? What are you trying to achieve having 1000 variables?

Comment: Are you limited in the expected number of *non-null* variables? ie - can you have more than 1?

Comment: Could you include: 1) what format these variables are in? Are they in a list? Why do you have a thousand different variables? How do you know only one of them is null? Since integers never are null, are you using `int?`? Could you show us some code to help us help you?

Comment: nullable int? , int can not be null

Comment: First of all, I thank you all for your answers.

Comment: First of all, I thank you all for your answers. I'm totally sorry, but I failed to describe my issue precisely. I have an object with say 7 properties (I only wrote 1000 to emphasize the fact that there are more than 3 variables - obviously I exaggerated..). Anyway, I can check each and every one of those  properties, or I can do..what instead? Thanks again, and sorry I misdirected you all - my bad.

Comment: why do you want to do that? You should check for null only where the property or variable is gonna be used.

Comment: Acc. **last edit**: _"I can check each and every one of those properties, or I can do..what instead?"_ You *must* check every property if you want to find the first null/zero. However, if these properties are similar (which your question suggests because you want to compare them) you should use a collection anyway. Not only for performance but for readability and maintainability reasons.

Comment: You want to check all properties of an object? Looks like a candidate for reflection. However this is still a bad idea. A broader picture is needed. Why would you like to iterate over all properties of an object?

Answer (score 5):

```
var value = yourList.First(i => i != null);
```

Taken that your list is of nullable types (int? or similar).

Edit: As mentioned after my answer you could use reflection to get all your properties, but since you asked for the optimal solution, I'd say you should fill your variables into a list (or array), and use my code above to find the first one that is not null.

If you must ensure that there's only one not-null you could use `Single()`, but `First()` is more efficient if you don't need to double check if there are any more values.

Comment: He has no `yourList`, read his last sentence again.

Comment: or you can use `HasValue`

Comment: @wudzik Yes, I typed it like that first, but that will work only with nullable value types, != null will work for every reference type.

Comment: I would not use First() unless absolutely certain there is at least one non-null variable. If there are is nothing in the collection, First() will throw an exception. Likewise, Single() will throw if there is more than one. Always use the `xxxOrDefault()` variant.

Answer (score 2):

this way you do not have to waste time entering codes to add the variables in the list, so this is the more effetive way.

```
class Foo {
    public int? A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
}

Foo foo = new Foo {A = 1, B = "abc"};
foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(int?)) // int? can be changed bythe type of your variable
    {
           if(prop.GetValue(foo, null) == null) // null can be changed to your verification, == 0  whatever.
           {
              //do some
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't! _"If you have 1000 different variables instead of a collection of 1000 elements you are doing something wrong"_ OP is looking for an efficient way not an unefficient,dangerous, less readable way.

Comment: If `typeof(int)` is true, then `prop.GetValue` will never be null.

Comment: I seriously doubt that reflection is more efficient than traversing an array.

Comment: typeof(int) will never be null

Comment: " (1000 integers) and say we know that only 1 of them is not null."

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob So you are making the assumption that they are in fact using `int?` because an `int` can never be null, even if the OP has incorrectly written such. At any rate, your code doesn't follow this assumption.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I changed my answer

Comment: @FedorHajdu I changed my answer

Comment: If OP already has 1000+ variables (i.e. not in a collection), he clearly doesn't mind writing some code :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter The 1000 different variables isn't instead of a collection. :)

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob: i assume you havent understood Jon's comment acc. to the 1000 variables. OP is asking for a way to prevent a collection like your reflection approach because he thinks that using single variables would be more efficient than  scanning a collection. Of course not.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But the waste time entering codes in a list can be 0 in this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var l = new List<int?>() { null, null, null, null, null, 1, null, null, null };
int?[] l2 = l.Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(l2[0]);
```

This is an example if you want get more than one variable, consider of use `.First()` if you need just one

Comment: Is there some reason you prefer `.ToArray()[0]` over `.First()`?

Comment: @Jon just a different approach

Comment: I would say "an unconditionally worse" approach, but I guess that's just a subset of "different".

Comment: @Jon he can use my example for get also more than one variable

Comment: @Sam No he can't, not if you take it verbatim. Obviously you are making reference to the use of `Where` versus `First`, in which case you are correct if we conveniently ignore the `.ToArray()[0]`. In fact your way is potentially dangerous because it assumes there is always at least one non-null value (I wouldn't cling onto the "and say we know there is only 1 non-null value bit personally).

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = listOfNullables.Single(e => e.HasValue == true);
var value = listOfNullables.First(e => e.HasValue == true);
```

Comment: You don't need Where, you can pass that lambda to Single(), but First() will be more efficient if he doesn't need to double check if there are more than one not-null in his collection.